# Command raised an exception: TypeError: object of type 'coroutine' has no len()

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

пытаюсь сделать что-то на подобии команды для случайного выбора пользователей, которые тыкнули на реакцию. Если быть проще: Giveaway Bot. Всем заранее спасибо.

```py
@client.command(aliases=['выбрать'])
async def pick(ctx, id):
    msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(id)
    user = msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    winner = random.choice(user)
    await ctx.send(f'`{winner}`')
```

Полный код ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/SecretSuperConfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/SecretSuperConfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/SecretSuperConfig/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: object of type 'coroutine' has no len()
```

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Reaction.users `await` кое-где забыли

Comment: Спасибо заранее